# Looking for an electronic copy of Kato's old paper

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, semigroups-of-operators

I would like to know if anyone has an electronic copy of the following paper:

> MR0279626 (43 #5347)
> Kato, Tosio
> Linear evolution equations of "hyperbolic'' type.
> J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. I 17 (1970), 241–258.

In my search, the best result I found was the [second article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-25/issue-4/Linear-evolution-equations-of-hyperbolic-type-II/10.2969/jmsj/02540648.full) published by the same author and an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266548/energy-methods-for-first-order-systems/266550#266550) by Willie Wong here on MathOverflow quoting this article.

Any information is welcome, for example, if this article is published in a book.

Comment: our library has it, I could make a copy (if no one else has it available)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I would really appreciate it if you can do this!

Comment: I have requested it, should take just a few days to get it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a copy (not surprising I suppose, since I made that answer earlier). Send me an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [pdf scan](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Kato_1970.pdf) of the article.

[image]